# Going inside if condition where it should not

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

My if condition in Python is not working. It is going inside the condition but it should not. Below is the code snippet:

```
a = np.nan

if a is not None :
   a = "".join(a)
```

The code is going inside the if condition and I don't know why.

Comment: `nan` *is not* `None`. They're two different things.

Comment: `np.nan is not None` trivially and by definition. Why do you expect otherwise? Do you understand what `is` means in Python?

Answer (score 0):

`np.nan` is not a type of None. You can check it by using `type(np.nan)`, which returns `<class 'float'>`.

np.nan is a class, it is not a None

Comment: `np.nan` is not a class. It is an instance of a class; but then so is None.